# How to Handle XML in Azure .Net Core Web App

Tags: xml, azure, xpath, .net-core, architecture

I have this problem to handle a large xml file that contains data indexed by states.
This >20 MB XML file has data for 50 states, multiple elements per state.

```
<statefip><"a name:value data structure containing various characteristics"/></statefip>
```

I need to generate visualization based on data inside the elements, one state at a time.
This file is received, periodically updated, from a data provider.
I expect to find a way to keep this XML in memory for my API to use Xpath to query and get nodes for one state.
Loading the whole file for every request to filter for one state seems pretty wasteful.

Various options on the table include:

1. putting it in  a redis cache. Redis does not support XML natively, so I cannot make an Xpath query to read relevant data.
2. Creating a database so then SQL can be used to read the records for a state. I think these reads are going to kill performance.

Must I translate this file into another format before I can use it.
This service works in Azure cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. One approach is to deconstruct the XML to a relational structure for db
   population, which is then queried per request. A 20MB XML is not
   huge, as XML is verbose.
2. Another option is to transform the file per request.  Note that you
   don't have to load the XML file for every request. You have it (and the XSLT) loaded, populate parameters from the request params, then transform.

The second approach may be expensive, but you might be able to chop the file into smaller files. That depends on what the information is and what requests you will support.

Which is most efficient depend on the data size and structure. Databases are efficient for querying and can be optimized for it. XSLT is good for efficiently changing (transforming) an existing document into another document.

So, 2 will be better if you want to retain most of the content of the document.

XPath querying of content is unlikely to beat database querying of an equivalent structure, unless there is a lot of nesting and you don't try to optimize the database or the querying.

I would create and XSLT of your result and do some tests on how long it takes before deciding.

Comment: Loading the file into a database is the conventional approach. My preference is your second bullet. In a request pipeline, can I have a singleton object that keeps this file loaded in memory for the requests to use Xpath to query it? Why you think it will be expensive? an in memory xpath to select a few nodes vs a hundred database reads.